# How to limit the Scope of element extraction between the start and end tag of a particular xml element using XPath in Python?

Tags: xpath, rdf, python-3.5, rdf-xml

I have an RDF/XML Element and would like to find out all the elements between the start and end of a particular tag. How could I do that?

for example :

```
<cim:BaseVoltage rdf:ID="_0526B48408F744919E7C03672FCD0D71">       
<cim:BaseVoltage.isDC>false</cim:BaseVoltage.isDC>  
<cim:BaseVoltage.nominalVoltage>400.000000000</cim:BaseVoltage.nominalVoltage>    
</cim:BaseVoltage>
```

I would like to extract the values BaseVoltage.isDC and BaseVoltage.nominalVoltage, since they are between the start and end tag of    . As mentioned this is just an example and I have many more such starting and ending tag.

I thought of doing it using Xpath, but am not really sure how.

Comment: Stop parse XML, learn RDF, use RDFLib.

Comment: Thats exactly what I finally used. Made things much easier. I finally used rdflib.Graph()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing the XML File using XPath seemed to be a really bad idea for the question. Rdflib makes it very easy.

```
import rdflib
from rdflib import Graph
from rdflib.namespace import Namespace

BASE = Namespace('http://example.org/')

graph = rdflib.Graph()
graph.parse('rdf.xml', format='xml', publicID=BASE)

for p,o in graph[BASE['#_0526B48408F744919E7C03672FCD0D71']]:
   print(p, o)
```

Comment: Please provide some example code, it would be helpful for CIM users.

Comment: I just entered a very simple example. It ofcourse needs to be edited as per needs.